# How to set up a method twice for different parameters with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I would like to set up a method with Moq twice but it seems that the last one overrides the previous ones. Here's my initial setup:

```
string username = "foo";
string password = "bar";

var principal = new GenericPrincipal(
    new GenericIdentity(username),
    new[] { "Admin" });

var membershipServiceMock = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
membershipServiceMock.Setup(ms =>
    ms.ValidateUser(username, password)
).Returns(new ValidUserContext { 
    Principal = principal
});
```

This works out fine but I want this to return `new ValidUserContext()` if the username or password is different to the `username` and `password` variables as above. To do that, I added another setup but this time it overrides the above one and always applies it:

```
membershipServiceMock.Setup(ms =>
    ms.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
).Returns(
    new ValidUserContext()
);
```

What is the most elegant way of handling this type of situation with Moq?

**Edit**

I solved the problem with the below approach but I guess there is a better way of handling this:

```
var membershipServiceMock = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
membershipServiceMock.Setup(ms =>
    ms.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
).Returns<string, string>((u, p) => 
    (u == username && p == password) ?
    new ValidUserContext { 
        Principal = principal
    }
    : new ValidUserContext()
);
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Moq supports this out of box with argument constraints:

```
mock.Setup(ms => ms.ValidateUser(
        It.Is<string>(u => u == username), It.Is<string>(p => p == password))
    .Returns(new ValidUserContext { Principal = principal });
mock.Setup(ms => ms.ValidateUser(
        It.Is<string>(u => u != username), It.Is<string>(p => p != password))
    .Returns(new ValidUserContext());
```

*Catch-all* `It.IsAny` also works, but the order is important:

```
// general constraint first so that it doesn't overwrite more specific ones
mock.Setup(ms => ms.ValidateUser(
        It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns(new ValidUserContext());
mock.Setup(ms => ms.ValidateUser(
        It.Is<string>(u => u == username), It.Is<string>(p => p == password))
    .Returns(new ValidUserContext { Principal = principal });
```

Comment: The first solution does not handle the case when u == username and p != password, or does it?

Answer (score 18):

If you look at the function definition for `Setup()`:

```
// Remarks:
//     If more than one setup is specified for the same method or property, the latest
//     one wins and is the one that will be executed.
public ISetup<T, TResult> Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression);
```

All you need to do is switch the **order** of the two `Setup()` calls:

```
membershipServiceMock.Setup(ms =>
    ms.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
).Returns(
    new ValidUserContext()
);
membershipServiceMock.Setup(ms =>
    ms.ValidateUser(username, password)
).Returns(new ValidUserContext { 
    Principal = principal
});
```

so if the input is indeed `username` and `password`, both `Setup()` calls are qualified but the later one wins because of the rule and when you have any other inputs, only the first one is matched and applied.

Answer (score 6):

Another out-of-the-box option is to use the Return<> version to return different ValidUserContexts depending upon the parameters.  It is not better than the above answer, just another option.

We set up ValidateUser() to return the result of a function GetUserContext(string, string), passing in the username and password with which ValidateUser() was called.

```
[TestClass]
public class MultipleReturnValues {

    public class ValidUserContext {
        public string Principal { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMembershipService {
        ValidUserContext ValidateUser(string name, string password);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DifferentPricipals() {

        var mock = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
        mock.Setup(mk => mk.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string, string>(GetUserContext);

        var validUserContext = mock.Object.ValidateUser("abc", "cde");

        Assert.IsNull(validUserContext.Principal);


        validUserContext = mock.Object.ValidateUser("foo", "bar");

        Assert.AreEqual(sPrincipal, validUserContext.Principal);


    }

    private static string sPrincipal = "A Principal";
    private static ValidUserContext GetUserContext(string name, string password) {

        var ret = new ValidUserContext();

        if (name == "foo" && password == "bar") {
            ret = new ValidUserContext { Principal = sPrincipal };
        }
        return ret;

    }
}
```